# Can't understand the storyboards in xcode 5

Tags: uitableview, storyboard, ios7, segue, xcode5

I can't understand the storyboards in xcode 5. I'm searching for the answers by doing manuals but nothing works, even simple storyboard scenes. Almost all of the manuals are on xcode 4.x, but I work in the fifth. As I understand there are some differences between the implementation of scenes in the xcode 4 and 5. I can't understand at all the principle of storyboards, and therefore do not understand why nothing works. Please help me to understand the difference between the xib and storyboard. What is the best for working and under what conditions? All the books which I have are about the IOS 6 and they're all with xib examples which I can't even run in the fifth xcode. Can't find adequate documentation on developer.apple.com, all confused. Аs I understand, the books about xcode 5 + IOS 7 will be released in a few months. Please, help me to make this scheme, the cells in the tableviews are static. Link to scheme https://www.dropbox.com/s/mwwfqgsj2d98exe/Scheme.jpg

Comment: you don't need story board and it can make thing more complicated if you have custom transitions and so on, dont bother just use plain xibs for your views.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an explanation for storyboards in Xcode 5 and specifics on how to make the connections between different scenes as identified in your scheme outlined in the image below:

**Starting with the big picture:**

1. To make segues between one scene or another you ctrl-drag from one **view controller** to a target **view controller** (you no longer need to ctrl-click from control to a different view)
2. In the source scene (document outline view) click the segue created
3. In the identity inspector create a unique name for the segue identifier
4. Any  control can now call the following view controller method to
   execute the segue - (void)performSegueWithIdentifier:(NSString
   *)identifier sender:(id)sender
5. One can pass data between view controllers by implementing the
   following method on the source view controller:-
   (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender

**So specific to your scheme:**

Within the Storyboard: 
Inside the Document Outline (Editor > Show Document Outline):

Expand two scenes

1. Ctrl-drag between ViewController1 to ViewController2
2. In the source scene, click the segue created and set the identifier in the identity
   inspector
3. In the source view controller, create the prepareForSegue described above to access and pass any
   data objects between view controllers (make sure you have a property
   on the target view controller, you use the segueIdentifier to control what data to send)
4. In the action method for the two buttons call the respective segue using a different id for View2 and View5 [self
   performSegueWithIdentifier:@"MYSEGUE_ID" sender:btnObjectNilEtAl];
5. To render segues to other view controllers just repeat the ctrl-drag process
   between a source and target view controller (View2 to View4/View5).
6. To have segues engage from the tableview cell simply add the [self
       performSegueWithIdentifier:@"MYSEGUE_ID" sender:btnObjectNilEtAl]; code into the didSelectRowAtIndexPath method.

Here are some code samples to get you started:

```
// In a story board-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before navigation
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{

    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"showDealDetail"])
    {
        // Get reference to the destination view controller
        DealDetailViewController *dvc = [segue destinationViewController];

        // Pass any objects to the view controller here, like...
        [dvc setDetailObject:(NSManagedObject*)sender];
    } else if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"showActivityDetail"])
    {
        ActivityDetailViewController * advc = [segue destinationViewController];

        // Pass any objects to the view controller here, like...
        [advc setDetailObject:(NSManagedObject*)sender];
    } else if ( [[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"showMatchDetail"])
    {
        MatchDetailViewController * mdvc = [segue destinationViewController];

        // Pass any objects to the view controller here, like...
        [mdvc setDetailObject:(NSManagedObject*)sender];
    }
}
```

From ViewController1 within the two button action methods call:

```
 //execute manual segue
        [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"showAlternate" sender: self];
```

[image: Scheme]

Comment: Sorry, don't quite understand. I decide to simplify my scheme https://www.dropbox.com/s/o82fxpte0hmyxcq/Scheme_Simple.jpg but it doesn't work. As I understand, I should set up navigation controller and cells of table view from View2.

Comment: `Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSGenericException', reason: 'Could not find a navigation controller for segue 'buttonOneSegue'. Push segues can only be used when the source controller is managed by an instance of UINavigationController.`

Comment: And this is my code https://www.dropbox.com/s/ep10zzj1buhlo12/Screen%20Shot%202013-10-10%20at%2011.52.17%20PM.png

Comment: @SashaKid - The error is stating that you are trying to use a push segue style. You can only do this if you start out with a navigation controller otherwise you must use either modal or custom as your current segue style. If you change your source controller to a navigation controller then and only then, you would use a push segue. To fix - Change the segue style by selecting the segue and in the attributes inspector select modal. Nothing wrong with your code except be aware that you need to setup a property on viewcontroller2 that will hold any data you want to pass in prepareForSegue.

Comment: @SashaKid - Keep in mind that in storyboards you drag segues between view controllers not view objects. Then call the two methods outlined above from the source view controller (whichever direction you are starting from). So if you drag a different segue back from vc2 to vc1 you would use the same set of methods to push data the other way with the exception that you might want to use [self dismissViewController... calls to unload vc2 when returning to vc1. Hope that helps and after you are comfortable don't forget to mark the answer.

Comment: I don't need pass any data, I want create only the segue. Thanks, I have changed push to modal but there is a problem with the table view: https://www.dropbox.com/s/1hazyhmk372ow4k/Screen%20Shot%202013-10-11%20at%2012.03.32%20AM.png I want to use static cells, what code should be?

Comment: @SashaKid - It looks like you are now correctly doing the segue. I suggest that you try the following. Just make two view controllers with static text so you can verify complete understanding of how the segues are called. I recommend you generate a new question for how to show static text in a tableview. Better yet just search stack overflow. I am certain this has been asked before. If my assistance was helpful please mark this question as answered (this will increase your reputation and encourage others to help you in the future)